# Why are my Bootstrap columns stacking and not horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am certain this question is asked a lot, but it seems to me that if I have the following code that there should be an column for title, and a column containing image, and two text blocks. 
While these show, they are not side by side, they are stacking, even when not in mobile mode: I thought that if you partition the column by fractions of 12, they would contain the content within the col, row, and container.

here is an example:

[image]

```
<body style="background-color: aliceblue;">


        <div class="TopBanner">
            <img src="~/images/massageBackground2.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%; background-position:center; background-repeat: no-repeat; " />
        </div>

        <div class="container ">

            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>My Philosophy</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="~/Images/massageBackground.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container  ">
            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>Types of Modalities</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="~/Images/massageBackground.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container  ">
            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>Benefits of Massage</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="~/Images/massageBackground.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container  ">
            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>Location and Fees</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="~/Images/massageBackground.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container  ">
            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>Reviews</h3>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="~/Images/massageBackground.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="container  ">
            <div class="row  ">
                <h3>Sitemap</h3>
            </div>
        </div>





</body>
```

Comment: Some Bootstrap versions don't have the "col-xs-" size, try "col-sm-"

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I am using the most current version of Bootstrap ... VS 2017 MVC

Comment: I have tried col-xs, col-md, col-lg, even just col and nothing seems to work ... this does not make sense to me, unless I just do not understand

Comment: You don't appear to have any CSS applied that isn't in the HTML. Provide an [mcve] showing where you `<link>` to bootstrap's CSS. Check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to make sure the URLs are resolving to what you expect.

Comment: Note that, in general, you should have one and only one element with `class="container"`.

Comment: so, I am all about trial and error, so I was creating this page without using a layout, the layout has the @Scripts.Render ... I copied those to my page, still having some issues, I think I will just create my own layout page or modify the current one

Comment: Can you see in the Browser´s developer section (F12) the references to the Bootstrap? By default when you create a MVC application it's include Bootstrap and jQuery and it's references in the _Layout view and by default you allways use the layout for rendering your views (at less that you manually remove it). By other hand, in Bootstrap 4 the modifier xs has been remove, you can use col-# instead.

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap isn't being applied at all. sure you've included it properly?

Answer (score 0):

A few things about Bootstrap, regardless of version.
first and foremost... `container`s must contain `row`s  which must contain `col`

[Per Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works):

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
>   columns may be immediate children of rows.

This markup goes against bootstrap docs:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <h3>whatever</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options) Per Bootstrap 4 docs:

> Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning
>   they apply to that one breakpoint and all those above it (e.g.,
>   .col-sm-4 applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices,
>   but not the first xs breakpoint).

If you are using version 4 there is no explicit `-xs-` column markup, so all your `<div class='col-xs-4'>` don't actually style anything. For `xs` just use `col` (autowidth) or `col-4` (explicit width)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>AutoWidths using only 'col'</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Explicit Widths using 'col-3'</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```